# How to get [UIImage] from camera (AVCaptureSession)

Tags: swift, uiimage, avcapturesession

I'm trying to add the UIImage I got from the camera to a [UIImage], but when I use the following code, the camera will stop after adding 12 frames

```
var temp1:CGImage?

extension VideoCapture: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {


    public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                              didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                              from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
       // print(1)
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }
//        print(sampleBuffer.imageBuffer)
        if let pixelBuffer = sampleBuffer.imageBuffer {
            // Attempt to lock the image buffer to gain access to its memory.
            guard CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly) == kCVReturnSuccess
                else {
                    return
            }
            // Create Core Graphics image placeholder.
            var image: CGImage?
            
            
            // Create a Core Graphics bitmap image from the pixel buffer.
            VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, options: nil, imageOut: &image)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if image != nil{
                    self.temp.append(image)
                    print(self.temp.count)
                }
                delegate.videoCapture(self, didCaptureFrame: image)
            }

//
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `UIImagePickerController` , you can develop using `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

ex.

```swift
var temp1:UIImage?

extension VideoCapture: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")] as? UIImage {
            
            // modified Image
            temp1 = image.convertToGrayScale()
            
        } else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")] as? UIImage {
            
            // original Image
            temp1 = image.convertToGrayScale()
        }
       
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```